# default <tr> tag attributes jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying out the following code and I expected the result to be false, but it is true. why is that so?

```
    String html = "<p><tr valign = 'top' />Link</p>";
    Whitelist whiteList = Whitelist.relaxed();
    whiteList.addAttributes("tr","align","bgcolor");
    boolean valid = Jsoup.isValid(html, whiteList);
    System.out.println(valid);
```

I also tried in the following way, the value returned is true

```
    String html = "<p><tr valign = 'top' />Link</p>";
    Whitelist whiteList = Whitelist.basic();
    whiteList.addAttributes("tr","align","bgcolor");
    boolean valid = Jsoup.isValid(html, whiteList);
    System.out.println(valid);
```

Even after adding

```
whiteList.removeAttributes("tr","valign");
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

EDIT-

I was able to get it running by making the following change

```
String html = "<p><table><tr valign='top'/>Link</table></p>";
```

I guess it was not parsed correctly because of the missing  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't close your `tr` tag when you open it like that, you need a `td` or a `th` to contain any content in a `tr`. And you can't embed a table row in a paragraph. Basically,

```
"<p><tr valign = 'top' />Link</p>"
```

should be something like

```
"<table><tr valign='top'><th>Link</th></tr></table>"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I guess I figured it out around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

because you have called `Whitelist.relaxed();` to construct `Whitelist`.

> relaxed(): This whitelist allows a full range of text and structural body HTML: a, b, blockquote, br, caption, cite, code, col, colgroup, dd, div, dl, dt, em, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, i, img, li, ol, p, pre, q, small, span, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, u, ul

You should use `Whitelist.none()` to construct.